# Python library or package for bifurcation analysis in ordinary differential equations

Tags: python, math, ode

What are libraries packages available in Python for the simulation and bifurcation study of dynamical systems?

I want to study the bifurcation phenomenon in ordinary differential equations. I know that there is [AUTO](http://indy.cs.concordia.ca/auto/) in Fortran. I also found [PyDSTool](http://www2.gsu.edu/~matrhc/PyDSTool.htm) in Pyhton. The issue with PyDSTool is that it has some incompatibilities with 64-bit systems and Python 3 (and also numpy, etc.). I was wondering if there is any state-of-the-art library in Python for this purpose.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything available in Python (except for PyDSTools and its interface with AUTO). You might check out the bifurcation suite in JULIA (which is also well suited to simulate and model dynamical systems): [http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/analysis/bifurcation.html][1]
[1]: http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/analysis/bifurcation.html
It is also built around PyDstools though but you might be able to circumvent your incompatibility problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.